# Move all classes to other class (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to write a js/jquery code that:

```
// if (@media (max width: 480px))
{
  please all classes `footer--column column--menu block` move to class
  `footer--columns block-group` and delete the `st--footer-column` class.
}
```

my HTML now:

```
<div class="footer--columns block-group">
  <div class="st--footer-column">
    <div class="footer--column column--menu block">...</div>
    <div class="footer--column column--menu block">...</div>
    <div class="footer--column column--menu block">...</div>
    <div class="footer--column column--menu block">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The final result:

```
<div class="footer--columns block-group">
  <div class="footer--column column--menu block">...</div>
  <div class="footer--column column--menu block">...</div>
  <div class="footer--column column--menu block">...</div>
  <div class="footer--column column--menu block">...</div>
</div>
```

I can use a jQuery, but this code must work only if max width be 480px.

Comment: are you planning to delete the div `st--footer-column`?

Comment: @Anandhu yes, this is very important too.

Comment: and you have to retain the contents of the div `st--footer-column` if I'm right. ?

Comment: yes, this is good idea, but the contents must be in div `footer--columns block-group`. Please, look at the final result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(window).on("resize ready",function(event){
    if($(window).width()<=480){
      var $content=$('.st--footer-column').html();
      $('.footer-columns.block-group').html($content);   
    }
});
```

the function is called on each resize and initial load

Answer (score 0):

I personally use window.innerWidth

```
if (window.innerWidth <= 480) {
    $('.footer--column.column--menu.block')
        .removeClass('footer--column')
        .removeClass('column--menu')
        .removeClass('block')
        .addClass('footer--columns')
        .addClass('block-group');
}
```

You can go on the jsfiddle and resize the render panel at less than 480px to see the result

http://jsfiddle.net/vjLrcsuk/10/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
if (window.innerWidth <= 480){
      $('.footer--columns').html($('.st--footer-column').html());
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="footer--columns block-group">
<div class="st--footer-column">
<div class="footer--column column--menu block">...</div>
<div class="footer--column column--menu block">...</div>
<div class="footer--column column--menu block">...</div>
<div class="footer--column column--menu block">...</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`window.matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) to determine if the media query matches and use jQuery's [`unwrap()`](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) on child `div`s to remove their wrapper.

```js
if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 480px)').matches) {
   $('.st--footer-column > div').unwrap();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="footer--columns block-group">
  <div class="st--footer-column">
    <div class="footer--column column--menu block">...</div>
    <div class="footer--column column--menu block">...</div>
    <div class="footer--column column--menu block">...</div>
    <div class="footer--column column--menu block">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this to remove them from the div

the div will be red when the `if` didn't execute

**took the if condition from @31piy 's answer**

```js
function changeHtml() {
  if ( (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 480px)')).matches ) {
    // get the div st--footer-column
    let sts = document.getElementsByClassName("st--footer-column");

    // since you didn't say there will be only one let's loop them all
    for (let i of sts) {
      while (i.childElementCount) {
        // appending the child to another Node remove them from their previous parent
        // I append them to the parent of the st--footer-column div
        i.parentNode.appendChild(i.firstElementChild)
      }
      // finally remove the now empty st--footer-column div
      i.parentNode.removeChild(i)
    }
  } else {
    let groups = document.getElementsByClassName("block-group");

    for (let i of groups) {
      let childrens = i.children;
      let stFooterColumn = document.createElement("div");

      // add the class
      stFooterColumn.classList.add("st--footer-column");

      // add each child to the new div
      while (childrens.length) {
        stFooterColumn.appendChild(childrens[0])
      }

      // append the div to previews to group
      i.appendChild(stFooterColumn)
    }
  }
}

window.onresize = changeHtml()
changeHtml()
```

```css
.st--footer-column {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer--columns block-group">
  <div class="footer--column column--menu block">...</div>
  <div class="footer--column column--menu block">...</div>
  <div class="footer--column column--menu block">...</div>
  <div class="footer--column column--menu block">...</div>
</div>
```

## same but without `if` for users on largescreen to test

removing the div

```js
// get the div st--footer-column
let sts = document.getElementsByClassName("st--footer-column");

// since you didn't say there will be only one let's loop them all
for (let i of sts) {
  while (i.childElementCount) {
    // appending the child to another Node remove them from their previous parent
    // I append them to the parent of the st--footer-column div
    i.parentNode.appendChild(i.firstElementChild)
  }
  // finally remove the now empty st--footer-column div
  i.parentNode.removeChild(i)
}
```

```html
<div class="footer--columns block-group">
  <div class="st--footer-column">
    <div class="footer--column column--menu block">...</div>
    <div class="footer--column column--menu block">...</div>
    <div class="footer--column column--menu block">...</div>
    <div class="footer--column column--menu block">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

adding the div

```js
let groups = document.getElementsByClassName("block-group");

for (let i of groups) {
  let childrens = i.children;
  let stFooterColumn = document.createElement("div");

  // add the class
  stFooterColumn.classList.add("st--footer-column");

  // add each child to the new div
  while (childrens.length) {
    stFooterColumn.appendChild(childrens[0])
  }

  // append the div to previews to group
  i.appendChild(stFooterColumn)
}
```

```html
<div class="footer--columns block-group">
  <div class="footer--column column--menu block">...</div>
  <div class="footer--column column--menu block">...</div>
  <div class="footer--column column--menu block">...</div>
  <div class="footer--column column--menu block">...</div>
</div>
```

---

Here's a second one showing the same but step by step (without the if)

using a [`generator function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*)

removing the div

```js
function* removeDivs() {
  // get the div st--footer-column
  let sts = document.getElementsByClassName("st--footer-column");

  // since you didn't say there will be only one let's loop them all
  for (let i of sts) {
    while (i.childElementCount) {
      // appending the child to another Node remove them from their previous parent
      // I append them to the parent of the st--footer-column div
      i.parentNode.appendChild(i.firstElementChild)
      
      updatePreview()
      
      yield true
    }
    // finally remove the now empty st--footer-column div
    i.parentNode.removeChild(i)
    updatePreview()
    yield false
  }
}

function updatePreview() {
  let div = document.getElementById("div")
  let arr = Array.from(div.children)
  
  document.getElementById("preview").innerHTML = arr.map(i => i.outerHTML.replace(/<div class=\"footer--column column--menu block\">/g, "<div class=\"footer--column column--menu block\">&lt;div class=\"footer--column column--menu block\"&gt;").replace(/<div class=\"st--footer-column\">/g, "<div class=\"st--footer-column\">&lt;div class=\"st--footer-column\"&gt;").replace(/<\/div>/g, "&lt;/div&gt;</div>")).join("")
}

remove = removeDivs()
updatePreview()

let interval = setInterval(() => {if(remove.next().value === false) {clearInterval(interval)}}, 2000)
```

```css
.st--footer-column {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="div" class="footer--columns block-group">
  <div class="st--footer-column">
    <div class="footer--column column--menu block">one</div>
    <div class="footer--column column--menu block">two</div>
    <div class="footer--column column--menu block">three</div>
    <div class="footer--column column--menu block">four</div>
  </div>
</div>

<br><br>
<div id="preview"></div>
```

adding the div

```js
function* removeDivs() {
  let groups = document.getElementsByClassName("block-group");

  for (let i of groups) {
    let childrens = i.children;
    let stFooterColumn = document.createElement("div");

    // add the class
    stFooterColumn.classList.add("st--footer-column");
    i.appendChild(stFooterColumn)
    updatePreview()
    yield true;

    // add each child to the new div
    while (childrens.length) {
      stFooterColumn.appendChild(childrens[0])
      updatePreview()
      yield true;
    }

    // append the div to previews to group
    updatePreview()
  }
  yield false;
}

function updatePreview() {
  let div = document.getElementById("div")
  let arr = Array.from(div.children)
  
  document.getElementById("preview").innerHTML = arr.map(i => i.outerHTML.replace(/<div class=\"footer--column column--menu block\">/g, "<div class=\"footer--column column--menu block\">&lt;div class=\"footer--column column--menu block\"&gt;").replace(/<div class=\"st--footer-column\">/g, "<div class=\"st--footer-column\">&lt;div class=\"st--footer-column\"&gt;").replace(/<\/div>/g, "&lt;/div&gt;</div>")).join("")
}

remove = removeDivs()
updatePreview()

let interval = setInterval(() => {if(remove.next().value === false) {clearInterval(interval)}}, 2000)
```

```css
.st--footer-column {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="div" class="footer--columns block-group">
    <div class="footer--column column--menu block">one</div>
    <div class="footer--column column--menu block">two</div>
    <div class="footer--column column--menu block">three</div>
    <div class="footer--column column--menu block">four</div>
</div>

<br><br>
<div id="preview"></div>

<br><br>
<div>could not find why the error at the end of this one</div>
```

Comment: works perfectly! :)
...but I must make a `@media (max-width: 480px)` tag.

Comment: @JsStorm2 I know I didn't add it on purpose to make the result visible on computer

Comment: Okay. It's good, but now I need a method, which will restore me code with the div.

Comment: @JsStorm2 doing this for you :p

Comment: @JsStorm2 added the onresize event at the same time